# Node xpath ignoring html tags?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath

I am trying to scrape a page and grab a couple of page elements with xpath. In my html , I have the following fragment:

```
<tr><th>Mailing Address:</th><td>10 BAY ST <br>STE 2000<br>NEWPORT BEACH, CA 92660 </td></tr>
```

(address is not real btw)

my node script has :

```
   const xpath = require('xpath');
   const dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
   var doc = new dom().parseFromString(element);
   address = xpath.select("string(//td)", doc);
   console.log(address);
```

The output I was expecting was:

```
10 BAY ST <br>STE 2000<br>NEWPORT BEACH, CA 92660
```

but I see:

```
10 BAY ST STE 2000NEWPORT BEACH, CA 92660
```

How can I get the inner text including tags?

Edit:

The tags themselves don't matter to me but they give positional information about the component parts of the address.

Comment: the <br> elements are incomplete when i test on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: I don't understand why that is important.

Comment: Because xpath requires a valid XML payload.  HTML <> XML.

Comment: One approach to solve this would be replacing all `<br>` with a `<br />` by a RegEx before processing.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, Is there a package in node that can handle xpath for html and is maybe a little more forgiving?